# The app crashes some seconds after launching on iOS 9.2.1 via Testflight

Tags: ios, crash, testflight, ios9.2.1

I distributed my app over Testflight: The app crashes some seconds after launching on iPhone 6s running iOS 9.2.1.

But when installing the app using Xcode on iPhone 6s - 9.2.1 devices, everything works fine too.

When launching the app using Xcode and distributed my app over Testflight on an other iPhone 6s running the latest 10.3.2 everything works fine.

If i testing wia testflight ios 9.2.1 app crashes every time at **random** **time**. Crash log show me absolutly difference reason at every crash

we are using Crashlytics and it has reported over **800** crashes, each one of those a singular crash that points to either an internal apple framework or private API. Some crash points to on our codes.

Most generated bug is:

```
# Crashlytics - plaintext stacktrace downloaded by Bkm ex at Sun, 04 Jun 2017 08:52:13 GMT
# URL: https://fabric.io/bkm-exs-projects/ios/apps/com.bkm.bkmexpressmobil/issues/5930ff20be077a4dcc8f95eb?time=last-seven-days/sessions/31c087d822b54534be973ada2bcc9f33_c0df8f95488b11e7a54356847afe9799_0_v2
# Platform: ios
# Version: N/A
# Issue #: 212
# Issue ID: 5930ff20be077a4dcc8f95eb
# Session ID: 31c087d822b54534be973ada2bcc9f33_c0df8f95488b11e7a54356847afe9799_0_v2
# Date: 2017-06-03T18:37:00Z
# OS Version: 9.2.0 (13C75)
# Device: iPhone 6
# RAM Free: 3.1%
# Disk Free: 3.3%

#1. Crashed: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos
0  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x180f03be8 szone_free + 2944
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x180f03738 szone_free + 1744
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1812159a4 CFRelease + 1088
3  CoreFoundation                 0x181254d38 readDataFinalize + 28
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1812f9d98 __CFStreamDeallocate + 128
5  CoreFoundation                 0x181215664 CFRelease + 256
6  CoreUI                         0x185e4fb90 __69-[_CSIRenditionBlockData expandCSIBitmapData:fromSlice:makeReadOnly:]_block_invoke + 640
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d89630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d895f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97a88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d020 start_wqthread + 4

--

#0. com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ebd4f8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d9aa38 _dispatch_group_wait_slow + 260
2  CoreUI                         0x185e4f818 -[_CSIRenditionBlockData expandCSIBitmapData:fromSlice:makeReadOnly:] + 892
3  CoreUI                         0x185e560a0 __csiCompressImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions + 1136
4  CoreGraphics                   0x1825c8390 img_blocks_create + 372
5  CoreGraphics                   0x1825b9dc8 img_data_lock + 1336
6  CoreGraphics                   0x1825b8e90 CGSImageDataLock + 140
7  libRIP.A.dylib                 0x192d7d670 ripc_AcquireImage + 732
8  libRIP.A.dylib                 0x192d7ca7c ripc_DrawImage + 620
9  CoreGraphics                   0x182625884 CGContextDrawImageWithOptions + 456
10 UIKit                          0x1860397e4 -[UIImage drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:] + 1404
11 UIKit                          0x186171620 -[UIImage(UIImageInternal) _isInvisibleAndGetIsTranslucent:] + 320
12 UIKit                          0x1860bfe78 -[_UINavigationBarBackground updateBackgroundImage] + 1292
13 UIKit                          0x1861c3744 -[UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics:] + 528
14 BKM_Mobil                      0x100176178 -[BKMNavigationController viewDidLoad] (BKMNavigationController.m:23)
15 UIKit                          0x1860280c0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
16 UIKit                          0x186027cc4 -[UIViewController view] + 28
17 UIKit                          0x18602eab4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 76
18 UIKit                          0x18602bfa0 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 252
19 UIKit                          0x1860a1cd0 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
20 BKM_Mobil                      0x1001033f4 -[BKMAppDelegate loginViewLoad:withTouchIdIsShow:forceLoad:] (BKMAppDelegate.m:324)
21 BKM_Mobil                      0x1001020c8 -[BKMAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (BKMAppDelegate.m:157)
22 UIKit                          0x18609d704 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 400
23 UIKit                          0x1862cc130 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2904
24 UIKit                          0x1862d04b8 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1672
25 UIKit                          0x1862cd5c0 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
26 FrontBoardServices             0x1828eb790 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184
27 FrontBoardServices             0x1828ebb10 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
28 CoreFoundation                 0x1812ecefc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
29 CoreFoundation                 0x1812ec990 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1812ea690 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
31 CoreFoundation                 0x181219680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
32 UIKit                          0x186096580 -[UIApplication _run] + 460
33 UIKit                          0x186090d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
34 BKM_Mobil                      0x1000e3688 main (main.m:10)
35 libdispatch.dylib              0x180dba8b8 (Missing)

#1. Crashed: com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos
0  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x180f03be8 szone_free + 2944
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x180f03738 szone_free + 1744
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1812159a4 CFRelease + 1088
3  CoreFoundation                 0x181254d38 readDataFinalize + 28
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1812f9d98 __CFStreamDeallocate + 128
5  CoreFoundation                 0x181215664 CFRelease + 256
6  CoreUI                         0x185e4fb90 __69-[_CSIRenditionBlockData expandCSIBitmapData:fromSlice:makeReadOnly:]_block_invoke + 640
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d89630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d895f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97a88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d020 start_wqthread + 4

#2. com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ed94fc kevent_qos + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d9c94c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d8b7bc _dispatch_source_invoke + 50

#3. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.work-queue :: NSOperation 0x126ea1510 (QOS: LEGACY)
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ebd4f8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d9a55c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 244
2  CFNetwork                      0x18198c584 -[__NSURLBackgroundSession setupBackgroundSession] + 540
3  CFNetwork                      0x18198bd34 -[__NSURLBackgroundSession initWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:] + 412
4  CFNetwork                      0x181a31130 +[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:] + 560
5  BKM_Mobil                      0x10024c904 +[CLSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:] + 4296902916
6  BKM_Mobil                      0x10022beac -[CLSNetworkClient session] + 4296769196
7  BKM_Mobil                      0x10022cf28 __76-[CLSNetworkClient checkForExistingTaskMatchingDescription:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 4296773416
8  Foundation                     0x181cdc334 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
9  Foundation                     0x181c2f100 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 96
10 Foundation                     0x181c1f348 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 604
11 Foundation                     0x181cde728 __NSOQSchedule_f + 224
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d895f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d95634 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d8d0f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97504 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d020 start_wqthread + 4

#4. AXBinaryMonitorQueue
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ebd4f8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x180f9697c _os_semaphore_wait + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d944ec _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 560
3  AccessibilityUtilities         0x18a46a1b0 __46-[AXBinaryMonitor _addHandler:withName:toMap:]_block_invoke + 128
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d89630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d895f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d95634 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d8d0f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d895f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97a88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d020 start_wqthread + 4

#5. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ed8b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d020 start_wqthread + 4

#6. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ed8b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d020 start_wqthread + 4

#7. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  BKM_Mobil                      0x10022ae00 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4296764928
1  BKM_Mobil                      0x10022ae00 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4296764928
2  BKM_Mobil                      0x10022b220 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4296765984
3  BKM_Mobil                      0x10021bed4 CLSHandler + 4296703700
4  BKM_Mobil                      0x100217214 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4296684052
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fb28 _pthread_body + 156
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fa8c _pthread_body + 154
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d028 thread_start + 4

#8. com.google.gmp.measurement.worker
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ebe80c pread + 8
1  libsqlite3.dylib               0x181877334 (null) + 3192
2  libsqlite3.dylib               0x1817f8b9c (null) + 13664
3  libsqlite3.dylib               0x181817b3c (null) + 5504
4  libsqlite3.dylib               0x181816ab8 (null) + 1276
5  libsqlite3.dylib               0x181888ffc (null) + 76096
6  libsqlite3.dylib               0x181837abc (null) + 50004
7  libsqlite3.dylib               0x18182b960 sqlite3_step + 504
8  BKM_Mobil                      0x10025c314 -[FIRASqliteStore validateDatabaseWithError:] + 4296966932
9  BKM_Mobil                      0x10025c22c -[FIRASqliteStore openAndValidateDatabase:] + 4296966700
10 BKM_Mobil                      0x1002596e4 -[FIRASqliteStore initWithDatabasePath:] + 4296955620
11 BKM_Mobil                      0x1002639e8 -[FIRADatabase initWithDatabaseName:persistedConfig:] + 4296997352
12 BKM_Mobil                      0x100271264 __48-[FIRAMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue]_block_invoke + 4297052772
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d895f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d8a434 dispatch_once_f + 80
15 BKM_Mobil                      0x100270f48 -[FIRAMeasurement startMeasurementOnWorkerQueue] + 4297051976
16 BKM_Mobil                      0x100270d3c -[FIRAMeasurement setIsEnabledOnWorkerQueue:] + 4297051452
17 BKM_Mobil                      0x10028282c __52-[FIRAScheduler scheduleOnWorkerQueueBlockID:block:]_block_invoke + 4297123884
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d89630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d895f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d95634 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d8d0f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97504 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d020 start_wqthread + 4

#9. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.binary-images
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ebd5b8 syscall_thread_switch + 8
1  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x180f99534 _os_lock_handoff_lock_slow + 120
2  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x180f04920 szone_free_definite_size + 684
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d895f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d95634 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d8d0f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d895f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97a88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x180d97224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d020 start_wqthread + 4

#10. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ed8b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d020 start_wqthread + 4

#11. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ebd4bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ebd338 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1812ecac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1812ea7c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4  CoreFoundation                 0x181219680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5  CFNetwork                      0x181989434 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6  Foundation                     0x181cf7c40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fa8c _pthread_body + 154
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d028 thread_start + 4

#12. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ed8b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d020 start_wqthread + 4

#13. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ed8440 __semwait_signal + 8
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x180df522c nanosleep + 212
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x18096e314 std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&) + 84
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x184b09bf4 bmalloc::Heap::scavenge(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >) + 188
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x184b098a4 bmalloc::Heap::concurrentScavenge() + 84
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x184b0bde4 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::entryPoint() + 100
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x184b0bd74 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::pthreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fa8c _pthread_body + 154
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d028 thread_start + 4

#14. WebThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ed7f90 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180fa239c _pthread_mutex_lock_wait + 96
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180fa257c _pthread_mutex_lock_slow + 296
3  WebCore                        0x184dcba2c _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 128
4  WebCore                        0x184dcb98c WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 44
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1812ec588 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1812ea32c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1812ea65c __CFRunLoopRun + 672
8  CoreFoundation                 0x181219680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
9  WebCore                        0x184dc9738 RunWebThread(void*) + 456
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fb28 _pthread_body + 156
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fa8c _pthread_body + 154
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d028 thread_start + 4

#15. JavaScriptCore::Marking
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ed7f48 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9ece8 _pthread_cond_wait + 648
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x180930074 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 56
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x1848b8a90 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 144
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x1848b8b28 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 84
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x18458e634 WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x18458e544 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fa8c _pthread_body + 154
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d028 thread_start + 4

#16. com.apple.CFSocket.private
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180ed8368 __select + 8
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1812f3028 __CFSocketManager + 648
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fb28 _pthread_body + 156
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9fa8c _pthread_body + 154
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x180f9d028 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace of the crash? It's hard to answer without more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very interesting bug. I use a image which is "Screen Shot 2017-05-12 at 03.03.24.png" on xcassets. So this image causes random crashes on iOS 9.2.1 and lower iOS 9

I should not have use image name which is contain point.
I lost my weekend :(

Comment: I also have random crashes on iOS 9.2.1 and lower, hot can I point on the problematic image?

Comment: İ was using an image with more than one dot in the image  name so it was causing crashes. For example: test.01.02.2018.png May be you use this kind of asset on your project.